# Android Bluetooth startDiscovery returns false

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to write a program that will list the available Bluetooth devices and allow the user to pair with them.

I have pieced together the code below. Unfortunately, the only intent that is called is `ACTION_STATE_CHANGED`, which occurs when I manually enable/disable Bluetooth on the device I am using for testing.

When I manually enable and disable Bluetooth on the device I am using for testing, it does trigger the intent, because I get the corresponding output. However, none of the other intents, such as "Discovery Started" are triggered.

When I run the `adapter.startDiscovery()` it always returns false, so I do not think it is looking for devices.

This code always returns the device address as 02:00:00:00:00:00

How can I fix this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter;
    private ListView mLvDevices;
    public static int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH = 1;
    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_bluetooth);

        BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
         filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBluetoothIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBluetoothIntent);

        }


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);



        System.out.println("Discovery"+adapter.startDiscovery());
        String mydeviceaddress = adapter.getAddress();
        String mydevicename = adapter.getName();
        System.out.println(mydevicename + " : " + mydeviceaddress+","+adapter.getState());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            System.out.println("Action"+action);
            if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                System.out.println("Started");
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                System.out.println("changed");
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                System.out.println("finished");
            } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                //bluetooth device found
                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

              // System.out.println("Found device " + device.getName());
            }
        }
    };
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.easyinfogeek.bluetooth">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.easyinfogeek.bluetooth.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if your app have the follow permissions before start discovery:

- Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
- Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;

Example:

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, 
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //without permission, attempt to request it.
                requestPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, PERM_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
```

Request Permission:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == PERM_REQUEST_CODE && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      //example permission granted
      //request startDiscovery again.
    }
}
```

Remember, if you want to enable/disable bluetooth a better way is
BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE and
BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISABLE.

BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISABLE is hide, but you can do it yet.

```
public static final String ACTION_REQUEST_DISABLE = "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISABLE";

//to enable bluetooth
Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

 // to disable bluetooth
 Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_REQUEST_DISABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISABLE_BT);
```